# How to send multiple arrays to client with websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am using ws in my node.js app. 
And I am trying to send 2 arrays to the client.
In one array (playlist) I have some urls, and in the other one (playlistTitles) I have titles for those urls.

SERVER-SIDE: Sending two arrays:

```
wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(playlistTitles)); //array 1
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(playlist)); //array 2
})
```

CLIENT-SIDE: Receiving two arrays:

```
ws.onmessage = function (event) {
    playlistTitles= JSON.parse(event.data); //array 1
    playlist = JSON.parse(event.data); //array 2
    console.log(playlistTitles);
};
```

Problem is console.log (playlistTitles) here outputs both arrays (first playlistTitles and then playlist), instead of just playlistTitles

And later **playlistTitles** displays content of **playlist** in it, which is unwanted.

So, how can I send these 2 arrays correctly or how should this task be approached?

Cheers, everyone!

Comment: I myself tag the objects being sent with my *websocket*. So I would add some discriminator to the data you send.

Answer (score 1):

The approach I mentioned in my comment:

```
wss.on("connection", function(ws) {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(["titles", playlistTitles])); //array 1
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(["list", playlist])); //array 2
})

//CLIENT-SIDE: Receiving two arrays:
ws.onmessage = function (event) {

    switch (event.data[0])
    {
        case "titles" :
            playlistTitles= JSON.parse(event.data[1]); //array1
        break;
        case "list" :
            playlist = JSON.parse(event.data[1]); //array 2 
        break;
    }
    console.log(playlistTitlesClient);
};
```